# Sample size of a prospective cohort study, where the prognosis will be assessed by a conventional method and a proposed method ?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

How to determine the sample size of a prospective cohort study, where the prognosis and outcome of disease will be assessed by an old conventional method and a novel proposed method ? We shall also compare the two methods to know whether the new method has got any advantage over the older method.

Answer (score 0):

For some time I've been trying to find a good answer to this question as well. This is what I've come up with:

In 2015 the [TRIPOD guidelines](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25560730) for the reporting of (diagnostic and) prognostic modelbuilding studies were published. In this guideline multiple recommended ways of estimating the required sample size are presented. For binary outcomes, the most well known is perhaps the 10 events per *parameter* rule of thumb. This rule states that for every *degree of freedom* spent, you need 10 events *of the least frequent outcome category*. 
For validation studies (studies where a previously developed model is tested in another population), this guideline recommends a minimum sample size so that you have at least 100 events (again, of the least frequent outcome category).

Recently however, I found the [following reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28459847) by Palazon-Bru et al, which proposed some interesting calculations for prognostic study sample size calculations. This is made specifically for validation studies, but is based on multiple prognostic performance measures you might be interested in.